# How can I handle both all-day and timed events while dealing with timezones?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, events, calendar

I'm creating a calendar that should supoprt both all-day events, and start/end times. The website also has to deal with the user's timezone.

My questions is:
- Events with a start/end time should be localized to the user's timezone, the day of the event may change, and that's the expected functionality.
- All day events should ALWAYS be the same date for all users.

I'm storing the dates in the database as UNIX timestamps, and I'm having trouble with dealing with both of these requirements gracefully.

Thanks!

Comment: `I'm storing the dates in the database as UNIX timestamps` - so you are storing a date/time as a string in the database? Then you are going to have to do all the work in your own code - the database can't really help much.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a single UTC datetime value and adjust it according to (1) user's timezone (See [CONVERT_TZ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)) and (2) an indicator on the event indicating if it is all-day or not. If not all-day, convert the datetime to a date (without timezone conversion), otherwise apply the timezone conversion mentioned above. If you want to save on database fields, use a second datetime for the end, leaving it null for all-day events.